# Getting data from Firebase Realtime Database returns nil Swift

Tags: swift, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsobject

I don't understand, I tried using `NSObjects`, I am able to print on screen a `String` value from my `Real Time Firebase Database` but when I try to assign it to a `UILabel` it crash with a `nil` value exception:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: is `weatherLabel` `nil`?, check your label `init`.

Comment: Yeah I'm probably dumb, I didn't connect the @IBOutlet to the label... now is working... -.-

Comment: ok glad to help :)

Comment: @elia if you want you can add your comment as an answer ;-)

Comment: hey Fabio, I added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `UILabel weatherLabel` is not `nil`. It seems value is not `nil`, so you better check your connection between `UIStoryboard` to your `UIViewController` to link your `UILabel` correctly.